# Read UART transmision Input buffer in Matlab

Tags: matlab, serial-port, fread, uart, input-buffer

I'm trying to make a serial communication between two ESP8266 Wifi chips.
To start, I tried sending a sample data 10 times in a for loop. Here is the code:

Transmiter:

```
for Packets = 1 : 10
    SendData(client,Data(Packets));
end
```

Receiver:

```
Packets = 1
while(1) 
    Data(Packets) = ReceiveData(Server);
    Packets = Packets + 1;
    if (packets == 10)
       break
    end
end
```

it works good. The problem is when I want to send data with some delays, the transmitter should connect to receiver again and the server (receiver) receives some data indicating that connection is made again.
The received Buffer should be:

```
+IPD,0,1024:ùüþþþýýþþÿÿûûýþýûúþÿúóýÿþþþþþýúøûýþ...
```

but after reconnecting the received Buffer is:

```
0,CLOSED   %Receiver Prompt, disconnected from Transmiter
0,CONNECT  %Receiver Prompt,connected to Transmiter
+IPD,0,1024:ùüþþþýýþþÿÿûûýþýûúþÿúóýÿþþþþþýúøûýþ...
```

The remaining part of data will be read in next packet and same for next packets.

what should I do to receive just the data?

The send and receive functions:

```
function ReceivedBuffer = ReceiveData(SerialPort)
         ReceivedBuffer = fread(server,1038); %Size data = 1038 Bytes
end

function SendData(SerialPort,Data) 
         fwrite(SerialPort,Data);
end
```